# How to redirect from subdomain.domain.com to domain.com using react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I would like to handle, if someone went to my react application from subdomain.domain.com.
Actually I can handle it using code like below:

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/"
  render={() => {
    const subdomain = getSubdomain();
    if (subdomain) {
      ... do something ...
    }

    return <HomeScreen />;
  }}
/>
```

but now I want to be able to redirect to main domain (without subdomain) `domain.com` instead of `subdomain.domain.com`. I've tried to use `<Redirect to="something" />` but the result is always like `subdomain.domain.com/something` (only add to url, not change it).

Is it possible to do something like this? I know that I can use `window.location.href` but firstly, it will forget state etc., secondly it will show browser popup about redirecting...

Comment: Why don't you handle it on server side? React-Router is for internal routing use, but not for navigation outside of the current domain.

Comment: I think you can't do such thing cause the subdomain is external source and it does not get handle the same way use a simple a tag